# React returns Error 'TypeError: ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract is not a function' when I trying to connect to my ethereum contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ether, ethereumj, react

I declared the variables as follows

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Web3 from 'web3';

  var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9545"));
  var contractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Candidates","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"age","type":"uint256"},{"name":"group","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getCandidate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_age","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_group","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"createCandidate","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
  var contractAddress = '0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10';
  var CandidatesContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddress)
```

But React returns a Type error as 'TypeError: ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract is not a function'

The same function working properly in Browser console, when i declare the variables directly put into the console?

can you please fix it?

Comment: Is ETHEREUM_CLIENT  loaded correctly?

Comment: Thanks @LuizSoares,                                                                               It is just because of the version of web3 that i'm using. I used a latest beta version, I think the function 'contract' is actually modified into 'Contract' in its latest version. So when i roll back to the web3 version 0.20 the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got solved**. It is just because of the version of web3 that I'm using. I used the latest beta version, I think the function 'contract' is actually modified into 'Contract' in its latest version. So when I roll back to the web3 version 0.20 the problem got solved